# I built a webscraper via python and I want to integrate it to a telegram bot but i keep getting a default page

Tags: python, telegram-bot

So i made a script that just scrapes for all hyperlinks on linkedin. i dont want anything else. this is what i did.

```
import re
import requests 
import logging
from telegram.ext import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime



url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_E=2%2C3&f_TPR=r86400&geoId=103644278&keywords=data%20analytics&location=United%20States'
    reqs = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')
    urls = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        words = link.get('href')
        if "jobs/view" in words:
            print(words)
    
ResultText = requests.get("https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/sendMessage?chat_id=[CHANNEL ID]&text={}".format(words))
import urllib

ParsedRestultText = urllib.parse.quote_plus(words)
```

so the for link in soup.findall it spits out everything properly in terminal like this :

[image]

but my telegram is showing me just the "community guidelines page" like this:

[image]

and occasionally, I will get a {} like this:

[image]

i looked at multiple documentations but i cant find one where they are JUST getting the hyperlinks and having it sent. It looks like i finally made the connection after many hours of figuring it out to my bot, but i dont understand as to why the hyperlinks are not getting sent to my bot that i built ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        words = link.get('href')
```

This just overrides the variable `words` in every iteration. If you want to gather all links that you find, you should probably append them to a list and use something like `', '.join(found_links)` as text to send. See the [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join) docs.

Answer (score 0):

`ResultText = requests.get("https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/sendMessage?chat_id=[CHANNEL ID]&text={}".format(words))`

Since this statement is outside of the `for` loop, you only get the last link that is **scraped**.

If you want to send all the links to Telegram Bot place the above statement inside the `for` loop. *(But this will result in multiple calls to your Telegram Bot API)*

Although the best approach would be to store all the links in a list and send that list to your Telegram Bot in one call.